# CalDAV calendar server SSL not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm building a java-ee application which should connect to an iCal CalDAV server using SSL.
I get this error every time I try to connect to the server.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
```

With other tools it worked fine, even with java tools after importing the certificate into the truststore.

If I try to connect using TLS I get a response that says, the server only supports SSLv3.
heres how I investigated the SSL handshake with the openssl tool

```
openssl s_client -host kalender.myserver.com -port 8443
```

this is what i get:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, OU = Root CA, CN = GlobalSign Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
 2 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
[[certificate]]
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.myserver.com
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3422 bytes and written 565 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 99D28660004D122D20657883562319F4F3063B1123AC882AD722B781EB13FF45
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 6228C28941D81771C68F0FA5546491804081294A95F4A2BE19AC239CF47C24752AC350F54BAEDD3C8E4A7E1044B4B429
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1406820530
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---
```

when i try

```
openssl s_client -tls1 -host kalender.myserver.com -port 8443
```

this appears and the connection fails:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139883471566496:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:337:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1407752794
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Here's how I investigated the SSL handshake with a Java tool I found [here](https://secure.marumoto.us/motowiki/tiki-index.php?page=Test+a+Java+SSL+connection).
I modified it so i can use another port.
to google:
`java HTTPSClient google.com` --> does not throw an exception
to my server on port 8443:
SSLv3: no error
TLSv1: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose SSLv3, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.`
I drew the conclusion that the server only supports SSLv3, so I tried to get my app to do that too, using a HttpClient provided by [apache](http://hc.apache.org/) but it does not seem to be compatible.
That means I have to say my app to use SSLv3, too. That would be somewhere in the `org.osaf.caldav4j.methods.HttpClient` class which inherits from `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`. The problem is, I can't find any way to do so.
I tried

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
```

and

```
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
```

but neither of them makes a difference. I also tried to somehow insert a custom `SSLSocketFactory` into the `HTTPClient` but found no way to do that. Here is the code to build the `HTTPClient`:

```
public HttpClient getHttpClient(String host, int port, String user, String password){        
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    String protocol = "https";
    String baseDir = "/calendars/users/" + user + "/calendar/";
    httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setHost(host, port, protocol);
    Credentials httpCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password);
    httpClient.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, httpCredentials);
    httpClient.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
    return (HttpClient) httpClient;
}
```

And this is the stack trace i get when i try to connect (i cut off the java-ee internal stuff):

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:702)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at org.apache.webdav.lib.methods.HttpRequestBodyMethodBase.writeRequestBody(HttpRequestBodyMethodBase.java:235)
    at org.apache.webdav.lib.methods.XMLResponseMethodBase.writeRequestBody(XMLResponseMethodBase.java:303)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.osaf.caldav4j.methods.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:103)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.osaf.caldav4j.CalDAVCollection.getCalDAVResources(CalDAVCollection.java:1029)
    ... 86 more
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to select SSLv3, JSSE will negotiate if the server responds properly which yours appears to do; and I think you shouldn't get bad_record_mac at all. If this server is or can be publicly accessible, https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest is an easy and pretty thorough test. Otherwise if you can look at the interaction with Wireshark or tcpdump or similar, or set javax.net.debug and grovel through it, and see what cipher is selected for a Java connection and try the equivalent with `openssl s_client` (some openssl cipher names are slightly different).

Comment: OpenSSL `s_client` does *not* have a `-port` option. I think you should use `openssl s_client -connect kalender.myserver.com:8443`. For TLS with SNI, use `openssl s_client -connect kalender.myserver.com:8443 -servername myserver.com`. See the [`s_client`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) docs.

Comment: @jww it does not make a difference if i use -host and -port or -connect. according to the docs you have to use -connect but i tested it and got the same output as with -host and -port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with just one line of code.

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.net.ssl.rsaPreMasterSecretFix", "true");
```

If I understand it right, I need this to tell Java to use the maximum supported version of SSL/TLS instead of some weird other one. You can check it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html). Anyways thanks for your help!